# Why is UFW blocking this connection?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I have a problem with a user who is unable to access a Ubuntu 22.04 webserver (he gets ERR_CONNECTION_RESET), apparently due to the firewall blocking his connections. However he IS able to access a different server on the same network, which has practically the same firewall configuration.

We have no other reports of a similar problem. Fail2ban is not installed. No IP specific rules are configured.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I should look next?

---

This is an example block from the ufw log:

```
Aug 22 12:38:45 docs kernel: [4546186.725262] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=52:54:00:5c:a4:04:02:00:00:00:00:01:86:dd SRC=2a01:cb06:b871:e0e0:0000:0010:1e4a:c601 DST=2a00:1098:00a4:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=60 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=48 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=49424 DPT=443 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
```

On the server he **can't** access, ufw is configured like this:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

The server he **can** access is almost identical:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    LIMIT IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Here is the output from ip6tables on the problem server, in case it helps:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 3781 packets, 243K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     817K  752M ufw6-before-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
2     817K  752M ufw6-before-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
3     3815  245K ufw6-after-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
4     3781  243K ufw6-after-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
5     3781  243K ufw6-reject-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
6     3781  243K ufw6-track-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ufw6-before-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
2        0     0 ufw6-before-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
3        0     0 ufw6-after-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
4        0     0 ufw6-after-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
5        0     0 ufw6-reject-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
6        0     0 ufw6-track-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    48140 8890K ufw6-before-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
2    48140 8890K ufw6-before-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
3     5920  553K ufw6-after-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
4     5920  553K ufw6-after-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
5     5920  553K ufw6-reject-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
6     5920  553K ufw6-track-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-after-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:137
2        0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:138
3       17  1088 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:139
4       17  1088 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:445
5        0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:546
6        0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:547

Chain ufw6-after-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       60  4000 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
9        0     0 ufw6-user-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-before-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0
2        0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
3    95480  712M ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
5      106  6468 ufw6-logging-deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
6      106  6468 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
9        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
10       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
11      11   620 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
12       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 133 HL match HL == 255
13    706K   40M ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 134 HL match HL == 255
14       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 135 HL match HL == 255
15    4338  278K ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 136 HL match HL == 255
16       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
17       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
18       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 130
19       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 131
20       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 132
21       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 143
22       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
23       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
24       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
25       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
26       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
27       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 144
28       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 145
29       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 146
30       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 147
31       0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       fe80::/10            fe80::/10            udp spt:547 dpt:546
32       0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ff02::fb             udp dpt:5353
33       0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ff02::f              udp dpt:1900
34   10411  723K ufw6-user-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-before-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      lo      ::/0                 ::/0
2        0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
3    37882 8025K ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
9        0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
10       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 133 HL match HL == 255
11       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 136 HL match HL == 255
12    4338  312K ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 135 HL match HL == 255
13       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 134 HL match HL == 255
14       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
15       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
16       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 130
17       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 131
18       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 132
19       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 143
20       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
21       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
22       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
23       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
24       0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
25    5920  553K ufw6-user-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-logging-allow (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw6-logging-deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       35  2100 RETURN     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
2        5   300 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-reject-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-input (6 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       34  2176 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-track-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      563 45040 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW
2     5357  507K ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW

Chain ufw6-user-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:80
3        0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:80
4      146 10840 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:443
5        0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:443

Chain ufw6-user-limit (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
2        0     0 REJECT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Chain ufw6-user-limit-accept (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-user-logging-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-logging-input (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-logging-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```